# Do I draw a card when I resolve an enchantment with Eidolon of Blossoms, Opalescence, and Torpor Orb in play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I control the following permanents:

[Eidolon of Blossoms](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=eidolon+of+blossoms)

> Whenever Eidolon of Blossoms or another enchantment enters the battlefield under your control, draw a card.

[Opalescence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=opalescence)

> Each other non-Aura enchantment is a creature in addition to its other types and has base power and base toughness each equal to its converted mana cost.

[Torpor Orb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=torpor+orb)

> Creatures entering the battlefield don't cause abilities to trigger.

Summary:

- Eidolon of Blossoms triggers a card draw when an *enchantment* enters play.
- Opalescence makes *enchantments* into *creatures*.
- Torpor Orb prevents *creatures* from triggering enter-the-battlefield effects.

So when I cast my next enchantment (that will be creature due to Opalescence), does it trigger the draw from Eidolon of Blossoms?

I anticipate the answer is no, but I wanted to confirm my suspicions.

Comment: Should we start considering a tag for "mtg-opalescence"?  :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eidolon of Blossoms will not trigger due to rule 603.6b.

> 603.6b Continuous effects that modify characteristics of a permanent do so the moment the permanent is on the battlefield (and not before then). The permanent is never on the battlefield with its unmodified characteristics. Continuous effects don’t apply before the permanent is on the battlefield, however (see rule 603.6d).
>
> *Example: If an effect reads “All lands are creatures” and a land card is played, the effect makes the land card into a creature the moment it enters the battlefield, so it would trigger abilities that trigger when a creature enters the battlefield. Conversely, if an effect reads “All creatures lose all abilities” and a creature card with an enters-thebattlefield triggered ability enters the battlefield, that effect will cause it to lose its abilities the moment it enters the battlefield, so the enters-the-battlefield ability won’t trigger.*

Let's use [Armistice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArmistice%5d) as an example of a non-aura enchantment that would be affected by Opalescence.

You cast and resolve Armistice. According to the rule, Armistice is never on the battlefield without being affected by the continuous effect from Opalescence. Therefore, the Armistice enters as a creature. Torpor Orb prevents creatures from triggering abilities, so nothing triggers.

Answer (score 7):

**No, you will not draw a card.**

With Opalescence on the battlefield, every other non-Aura enchantment enters the battlefield as a creature in addition to as an enchantment. Normally they would trigger Eidolon, but Torpor Orb prevents that. Logically, you couldn't have Eidolon trigger on a permanent but not have it prevented by Torpor Orb, they trigger on/prevent the same condition. Either both have their effect, or neither.

Comment: I am not sure this is correct since wouldn't an enchantment such as Pacifism still trigger Eidolon of Blossoms since it won't get turned into a creature with Opalescence since it is an aura?

Comment: @JoeW No, OP asked about *So when I cast my next enchantment (that will be creature due to Opalescence),*

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I missed that critical part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Whether you draw a card or not will depend on the enchantment being cast.**

> Opalescence makes *enchantments* into creatures.

Actually, Opalescence makes *other non-Aura enchantments* into creatures. That means that Auras and Opalescence itself are not affected by its effects, so the Eidolon's ability will resolve normally if you've either cast Opalescence or an Aura enchantment.

For other kinds of enchantments, however, Opalescence will have them become a creature as soon as they enter the battlefield, and Torpor Orb's ability will prevent the Eidolon's from triggering.

Comment: To clarify, casting Opalescence when no Opalescence is on the battlefield will draw a card. Casting a second Opalescence *would not* draw a card because each Opalescence can affect each other (it says "other non-aura enchantment" not "non-aura enchantment not named 'Opalescence'")

Answer (score 2):

Non-aura enchantments won't trigger the Eidolon.

Other answers have focused on Opalescence and how its state-based effect interacts with enters-the-battlefield triggers, but there's another aspect of your question that might be a source of confusion: Torpor Orb specifically refers to *creatures*, but non-aura enchantments would still also be *enchantments*, which is what the Eidolon's ability checks for. It's kind of plausible to interpret this distinction in favor of the Eidolon triggering, but it's not correct.

I haven't been able to find anything in the comprehensive rules that explicitly addresses this, but there's a card ruling on Torpor Orb that clears up some doubt:

> The trigger event doesn’t have to specify “creatures” entering the battlefield. For example, Amulet of Vigor says “Whenever a permanent enters the battlefield tapped and under your control, untap it.” If a creature enters the battlefield tapped and under your control, Amulet of Vigor would not trigger. If a land (that isn’t also a creature) enters the battlefield tapped and under your control, Amulet of Vigor would trigger.

(See [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233069))

Essentially, Torpor Orb's effect is about a class of *events* - i.e. a permanent whose types include creature ETBing - rather than a class of *abilities* - i.e. those that trigger in response to permanents whose types include creature ETBing.

Answer (score -3):

Eidolon of Blossoms effect does activate when the enchantment is cast, since Opalescence would change it afterwards to be a creature as well. The effect of Opalescence only affects enchantments that are on the field, meaning it would chain alongside Eidolon (allowing you to pick how they go, so let Eidolon's effect resolve first by making it chain 2).Torpor Orb will not have any response then, has a creature has not yet entered the fray.

Comment: That's not how it works. Opalescence's ability is a static ability, and it applies as soon as an enchantment enters the battlefield.

Comment: I am not one of the down voters, however, there are multiple mistakes in this answer.  Eidolon does not "activate," it "triggers."  Eidolon triggers when the enchantment enters the battlefield, which is not the same timing as when you cast it.  Opalescence will cause an enchantment to enter the battlefield as a creature and trigger anything that triggers when creatures enter the battlefield.  It is worth noting, though, that Opalescence will not turn enchantment spells into creature spells, so an enchantment spell can't be countered with Remove Soul.